# MySQL Min/Max bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I want to get the minimum/maximum value from the temperature data (daten_temp) of my weatherstation.
My database name is "wetterdaten" and in this example I want to get the minimum value from january (daten_monat = 01) in this year (daten_jahr = 2019).
The temperature data looks like this e.g. (format): -0.9 or 14.1 ... etc.
The result is: -0.1 but I think I need -9.4 or something like this.
Anybody have a solution?

PHPmyadmin, MySQL 5.6.42, (PHP 7.2)

```
SELECT MIN(daten_temp)

FROM wetterdaten

WHERE daten_monat = '01'
AND daten_jahr = '2019'
```

```
MIN(daten_temp)     
-0.1
```

The result is -0.1 but i need something like -9.4

Comment: What's the data type you declared for the `daten_temp`? If it's a string type like VARCHAR, it's using alphabetical order, not numeric order, to determine the minimum value.

Comment: Oh, I think you get it! It's VARCHAR, can I change it to INT or are there problems then?

Comment: @Freddy Not `int`! To `float`, `double` or `numeric`/`decimal` of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is stored as a string, then you need for it to be interpreted as a number.  As strings are sorted, `'-0.1'` is indeed smaller than `'-9.4'`, because 0 is smaller than 9.

A simple mechanism in MySQL is to add `0` to the value to convert to a number:

```
SELECT MIN(daten_temp + 0)
FROM wetterdaten
WHERE daten_monat = '01' AND daten_jahr = '2019';
```

That said, temperatures are numbers and should be stored as such.  I would recommend:

```
alter table wetterdaten modify column daten_temp decimal(6, 3);
```